# Why is my ASP.NET MVC persistent auth cookie not working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3, with forms authentication (based on modified vanilla account code you get with file->new).

When you login, I am setting an auth cookie with

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
```

So this should set a persistent cookie. But if I close the browser and re-open, when I browse to the site I am forced to log in again! I can see using chrome dev tools that the cookie (.ASPXAUTH) is being created and not being deleted when I close the browser, so what's happening?

My web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogIn" timeout="10000"/>
</authentication>
```

I'm testing this locally, under IIS if that makes any difference.

Comment: you can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682788/making-user-login-persistant-with-asp-net-membership

Comment: Ok, this link seemed to sort it for me - sticking with SetAuthCookie and tweaking my config to explicitly set the cookie name (in the web.confg), and all is working now. Weird!

Comment: @Matt Roberts - I have no idea why but setting the cookie name fixed it for me too. You'd think it'd just work with the cookie being domain specific etc. Is this a bug in MVC or .NET maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved from comment from @alexl:

you can check this answer: [Making user login persistant with ASP .Net Membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682788/making-user-login-persistant-with-asp-net-membership)

Ok, this link seemed to sort it for me - sticking with SetAuthCookie and tweaking my config to explicitly set the cookie name (in the web.confg), and all is working now. Weird! –

Answer (score 10):

I'd better create myself a cookie using authentication ticket.
`SetAuthCookie` creates an auth ticket under the hood. Have you tried making your own auth ticket? It **will let you store extra data on it**.

Here's an example :

```
// create encryption cookie         
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, 
        userName, 
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddDays(90),
        createPersistentCookie, 
        string.Empty);

// add cookie to response stream         
string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);    
System.Web.HttpCookie authCookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
if (authTicket.IsPersistent) 
{     
      authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration; 
}
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. So I shouldn't use SetAuthCookie at all? The MSDN documentation tells me to use that to create an auth cookie which can be persistent. Also, the vanilla code for a new MVC app uses SetAuthCookie - is that wrong?

Comment: SetAuthCookie() is doing globally the same. It's just weird because it seems it doesn't work all the time. I prefer to create myslef an authentication ticket and add it to the response stream.

Comment: check also the link @alexl posted as a comment to your question.

Comment: Seem to have it working now (see comment on question), using SetAuthCookie. Thanks.