# .aspxauth Not being used

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

When I use the following code:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userId.ToString(), true);
```

an .aspxauth cookie is created with a correct expiration date.

However when i close all instances of the browser and return to the page, I am no longer logged in. I also do not see the cookie in firebug. When I search for the cookie in the browser (I choose remove a cookie, and search for .ASPXAUTH) I do see that it is there.

Any clues for this behavior? Thanks!

In the web.config:

```
authentication mode="Forms"
forms timeout="28800" 
authentication
```

Comment: Do you return to a regular page or the login page? The forms login page clears the cookie AFAIK.

Comment: Authentication cookie by default has browser session lifetime. So when you close all the browser windows cookie gets removed

Comment: @AlexandrMihalciuc this is not the case as I set true in SetAuthCookie

Comment: @fejesjoco The login page is a partial that all the pages has. I will look into what you wrote

Comment: Can you post your <authentication> section of web.config?

Comment: @faraw, can you try these suggestions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852057/why-is-my-asp-net-mvc-persistent-auth-cookie-not-working