# Invalid viewstate error on postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iis-7, viewstate

I am getting the following error when the user tries to submit a form, it only happens sometimes... Not sure how to resolve or what the root cause could be. Any help is appreciated. Please see below for screenshot..
Framework 4.0, IIS7
http://s12.postimage.org/69txogmwr/Untitled.png

Comment: The answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576990/should-i-ignore-the-occasional-invalid-viewstate-error) may help you out. If I had to guess I'd say check the machine key settings. I've seen this error happen when an application recycles and a machine key is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Things that I have seen cause this:

- machinekeys out of sync in a webfarm
- page loads slow and the user posts back before it's finished
- page sits idle after partial postbacks and the app pool is recycled
- page sits idle, new code is deployed for page/controls, first postback dies due to mismatched controls