# Page not updating, but is working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a page where users select people, they view the personal details of the person selected.

This page has worked great for 6 months, but a few days ago I'm encountering a problem. When someone selects the person, it does work like it's supposed to according to the debugger, but the textboxes still show the old person until I refresh the page. This only happens sometimes, not all the time.

Using

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Seems to help.

This coincides with the timing of my other post:
[Random Invalid Viewstate Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006400/random-invalid-viewstate-error)

I can't identify what would suddenly cause this problem, cache or viewstate or something else?

Comment: Did you try clearing temperate files in browser...?

Comment: its for multiple users